# Manga in which the main character got multiple classes at once and met a princess who made him her bodyguard

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character has a childhood friend who got the holy knight class and his brother did too and his class was mimic or something like that. When he touched someone, he got his class and could use multiple classes at once. He met a princess who could use appraisal and she made him a royal guard and her bodyguard.

Comment: Hi. It sounds like this is an isekai manga, i.e. one where the main character is transported to another world. Is that correct? And if so, was he transported with just his childhood friend and his brother, or were other people transported as well?

Comment: they immediately started in such a world, they were not transferred, his brother was from some extended family, they did not have a good relationship

Comment: Was the childhood friend male or female?